# Implement this kind of app

Tags: node.js

How do I create a node script, that does something like this:
(Basically, I just want a flow on how to go about this, like where to use sync, async and callbacks).

```
[On start / Run once]
- Check If file (local copy json) exists
|---Yes - Load from file
|---No  - Get new data and store in file

- Every 5 minutes, run
|---Get new data (json)
|---Check if new item
|------Yes - Trigger alert
|------No  - Don't do anything
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[On start / Run once]
- Check If file (local copy json) exists
|---Yes - Load from file
|---No  - Get new data and store in file

- Every 5 minutes, run
|---Get new data (json)
|---Check if new item
|------Yes - Trigger alert
|------No  - Don't do anything
```

It is fine for you to have 2 different functions.

For the run once on start code, just place it within the first function at the start of your code. As for the other function with time interval, you can use the `setInterval` function.
Ultimately, there is no reason for your to use synchronous methods (promises) since they will not affect each other.

As for callbacks, they will just  follow from each of the two functions accordingly to your structure. You are already on the right track.